# Set drop down menu of Action bar invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-actionbar

I am using Android native action bar in my app. I created the drop down menu of action bar by:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);      
    return true;
}
```

For certain page, I would like to **hide** the action bar drop down menu. How to achieve this? Seems there is no direct method to set visibility to false for this drop down menu...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this problem myself by set each menu item in drop down menu of action bar to be invisible:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu); 

    menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(3).setVisible(false);     

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to change the navigation mode of action bar when you create the activity...

```
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

Comment: It does not work. I would like to hide the drop down menu of action bar in a Fragment not activity, well, I defined the action bar in activity

Comment: did you try something like fragment.getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(...) ?
You should try to call this method in fragment's onCreateView

Comment: Yes, I tried that. the drop down menu is still showing on action bar

Comment: what about inflating a menu with null array? remember that, if your using compatibility package, you should call "getSupportActionBar" instead of getActionBar.